# Using a cell's value in a function to fetch data from a different sheet - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two google sheets: `sheet1` and `sheet2`.  In `sheet1` I have in cell `A1` this the text `"sheet2!b2"`.  How do I reference `A1` in cell `A2` to be able to pull the ACTUAL data from `sheet2!b2`?  When I try to use in a formula, i just get the `sheet2!b2` text... it does not pull the value from `sheet2`.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Look into: INDIRECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RemcoE33 said in your comment, you can use the `Indirect` formula, it takes a string in the formula, so you can reference it as:

- `Indirect(A1)` (as seen in the image below, or
- `Indirect("Sheet2!B2")`

(the value of my `sheet2!b2` is `Hello`, so you can see it works. For more information you have the documentation of [Indirect](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

[image]